# Configuring Keycloak to handle MySQL connection timeouts

Tags: mysql, mariadb, keycloak, quarkus

I am facing a problem where MySQL closes connections after a certain timeout period, and Keycloak subsequently encounters errors because it tries to reuse these closed connections.

How can I set up Keycloak to automatically discard and refresh stale connections with MySQL?

Note that I use a managed service without complete access to the database configuration, so reconfiguring IDLE/stale connection lifetime is not an option.

The [documentation of all build options and configuration for Keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config#category-database) do not contains such advanced DB configuration. Maybe is this [configurable via Quarkus](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_format_for_raw_quarkus_properties)?

Answer (score 0):

This can be configured using Quarkus. Create a [`quarkus.properties` file in the `conf` directory](https://www.keycloak.org/server/configuration#_format_for_raw_quarkus_properties) containing the [datasource/JDBC options](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#quarkus-agroal_configuration).

Example:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval=PT29S
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime=PT29S
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.background-validation-interval=PT29S
quarkus.transaction-manager.enable-recovery=true
```